# How to optimize spotify loading?

Tags: 14.10, spotify

Will having 0 playlists allow spotify to load faster? I feel that when I run it (from the command line) playback is very very slow for the first couple of minutes, and a lot of lines are appearing on terminal. Then things run smoothly.

I enter ... to signify about 20 lines of playlists.
user #s were changed to z for anonimity

```
15:51:06.911 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:rootlist] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 471,a150e2f115ce2888d314b8e92242d0b4484cccc1) 
15:51:06.922 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:7cjxPoE4LPJnBV6ZtwoWlI] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 1,cb50b271f1e90bf237abfcff0d1f91de36360da0) 
15:51:06.946 I [AppManager.cpp:258              ] Creating instance of the application browse.
15:51:06.958 I [AppManager.cpp:258              ] Creating instance of the application suggest.
15:51:06.969 I [AppManager.cpp:258              ] Creating instance of the application notification-center.
15:51:06.970 I [AppManager.cpp:541              ] Removing instance of application notification-center.

15:51:06.981 I [AppManager.cpp:258              ] Creating instance of the application notification-center.
15:51:06.989 I [offline_manager.cpp:2353        ] Storage has been cleaned
15:51:06.989 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:collectionrootlist] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 2,54cadf6a56ec5895471005cf8a804fbc1d7bf4b4) 
15:51:07.055 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 471,a150e2f115ce2888d314b8e92242d0b4484cccc1) 
15:51:07.115 I [AppManager.cpp:258              ] Creating instance of the application feed.
15:51:07.216 3 [playlist_be_toplist.cpp:233     ] [spotify:user:z:top:tracks] Synchronization starting
15:51:07.328 I [MainView.cpp:6828               ] Load complete (0) url: sp://ff9d37cf876c1074eb5f62b059c1594f317d685c.feed/index.html
15:51:07.427 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:inbox] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 103,11302267144c37096bb7e1679b4f55a0c956d394) 
15:51:07.548 I [MainView.cpp:6828               ] Load complete (0) url: sp://38c77ecc7b659570b5f3edb3f83c0cf13c8a56e8.browse/index.html
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
15:51:15.516 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:901      ] Connecting to AP sjc1-accesspoint-a5.ap.spotify.com:4070
15:51:20.543 E [ap_connection_impl.cpp:837      ] AP Socket Error: Timeout reached (20000)
15:51:20.543 E [ap_handler_impl.cpp:872         ] Connection error:  ap_tcp_socket_timeout
15:51:20.544 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:901      ] Connecting to AP sjc1-accesspoint-a101.ap.spotify.com:443
15:51:24.981 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:530      ] Connected to AP: 194.68.29.194:443
15:51:28.472 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3465132) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusStopped
15:51:28.472 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1249          ] GAIA: TIMING(3465133) SpircManager::sendSubscribe
15:51:28.472 D [spirc_manager.cpp:267           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stateTransition, kServiceStatusStopped->kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:51:28.474 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3465134) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:51:28.475 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3465136) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:51:28.477 I [sliding_window_prefetch_strategy.cpp:329] Prefetch: looks like new context - resetting window size to 1
15:51:28.984 3 [playlist_be_toplist.cpp:136     ] [spotify:user:z:top:tracks] Updated
15:51:28.985 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:rootlist] Delta-updated to revision 471,a150e2f115ce2888d314b8e92242d0b4484cccc1 (no new changes)
15:51:28.991 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:collectionrootlist] Delta-updated to revision 2,54cadf6a56ec5895471005cf8a804fbc1d7bf4b4 (no new changes)
15:51:28.997 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:7cjxPoE4LPJnBV6ZtwoWlI] Delta-updated to revision 1,cb50b271f1e90bf237abfcff0d1f91de36360da0 (no new changes)
15:51:29.019 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:inbox] Delta-updated to revision 103,11302267144c37096bb7e1679b4f55a0c956d394 (no new changes)
15:51:29.021 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:607 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist]  synchronization error: Hermes error code 405 (unknown)
15:51:29.021 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:716 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist]   - requesting HEAD from remote.
15:51:29.022 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:6EseKk7zxt6LbVcrxwVg5P] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 41,a115f50dfc18377f159e23ebe6ce6edf9463db22) 
15:51:29.022 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:4wtLaWQcPct5tlAWTxqjMD] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 482,94eb7f8e8b5729cc9875c87183b4f1cad19e5b9a) 
15:51:29.022 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:collectiontracklist:4b7m4G1kFBoAjdxuHdUAqs] Synchronization starting:      DIFF (from revision 67,c886a4b84f1a42a7b50d79def8b032e926b7cc9a) 
15:51:29.022 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5xtPbr795elinw40DsMnTY] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 585,7d250316cc798fdb3adc2f7a8f1ab7b5aed2c1bb) 
15:51:29.022 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:0LhFE8c74NK7d8rNYsudrf] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 35,b7d5bc6e032420fb529a03b057507d40f0c2b19b) 
15:51:29.129 I [MainView.cpp:6828               ] Load complete (0) url: sp://ff9d37cf876c1074eb5f62b059c1594f317d685c.feed/index.html
15:51:29.185 I [MainView.cpp:6828               ] Load complete (0) url: sp://38c77ecc7b659570b5f3edb3f83c0cf13c8a56e8.browse/index.html
15:51:30.151 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1312          ] GAIA: TIMING(3466811) SpircManager::onSubscriptionSuccess
15:51:30.151 D [spirc_manager.cpp:267           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stateTransition, kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx->kServiceStatusRunning
15:51:30.152 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1378          ] GAIA: TIMING(3466812) SpircManager::sendHelloHelper
15:51:30.829 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:4wtLaWQcPct5tlAWTxqjMD] Delta-updated to revision 482,94eb7f8e8b5729cc9875c87183b4f1cad19e5b9a (no new changes)
15:51:30.831 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5xtPbr795elinw40DsMnTY] Delta-updated to revision 585,7d250316cc798fdb3adc2f7a8f1ab7b5aed2c1bb (no new changes)
15:51:30.832 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:6EseKk7zxt6LbVcrxwVg5P] Delta-updated to revision 41,a115f50dfc18377f159e23ebe6ce6edf9463db22 (no new changes)
15:51:30.832 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:0LhFE8c74NK7d8rNYsudrf] Delta-updated to revision 35,b7d5bc6e032420fb529a03b057507d40f0c2b19b (no new changes)
15:51:30.832 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:collectiontracklist:4b7m4G1kFBoAjdxuHdUAqs] Delta-updated to revision 67,c886a4b84f1a42a7b50d79def8b032e926b7cc9a (no new changes)
15:51:30.851 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Synchronization starting: GET (full reset) (cannot send dump) (from revision 471,a150e2f115ce2888d314b8e92242d0b4484cccc1) 
15:51:30.852 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 132,431ef37f4820b65b00cbb78588c7f131fde7b620) 
15:51:30.852 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:3r4GXRrOK8dMrUHwa9tYKM] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 1,5cc22b8223f27511b18512142e908ede60e94bf0) 
15:51:30.852 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 1837,6e2a70db85fcead0f9ee01e4414a913667b980c0) 
15:51:30.854 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:71oHxgERzA8JV1bHBJW0z1] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 81,900909781aa0ace5ba8e61f94969793c3f12e1f9) 
15:51:33.151 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1407          ] GAIA: SpircManager::hermesDeviceCheck
15:51:33.961 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:607 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist]  synchronization error: Hermes error code 405 (unknown)
15:51:33.961 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:716 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist]   - requesting HEAD from remote.
15:51:33.961 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:607 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist]  synchronization error: Hermes error code 405 (unknown)
15:51:33.961 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:716 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist]   - requesting HEAD from remote.
15:51:33.962 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:3r4GXRrOK8dMrUHwa9tYKM] Delta-updated to revision 1,5cc22b8223f27511b18512142e908ede60e94bf0 (no new changes)
15:51:33.963 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:71oHxgERzA8JV1bHBJW0z1] Delta-updated to revision 81,900909781aa0ace5ba8e61f94969793c3f12e1f9 (no new changes)
15:51:33.964 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Synchronization starting: GET (full reset) (cannot send dump) (from revision 132,431ef37f4820b65b00cbb78588c7f131fde7b620) 
15:51:33.964 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Synchronization starting: GET (full reset) (cannot send dump) (from revision 1837,6e2a70db85fcead0f9ee01e4414a913667b980c0) 
15:51:33.974 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:1002] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Snapshot-updated to revision 471,a150e2f115ce2888d314b8e92242d0b4484cccc1
15:51:33.983 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:3wmadCOASzVtYyFNM48mYk] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 157,865c3d172d544a96188776ffbc1bc3c914d8fe06) 
15:51:33.984 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:7g6K4NOFD2eLb3i7KbmMdK] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 52,c7a9f51eee232f398a4c6951a2439342b00d69a5) 
15:51:33.995 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:0G4dLya8wKCG4P6e4p2m6c] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 25,10178c3886bdb8e2d6e52cbaced5b9f8c94869e6) 
15:51:34.757 I [kindling.js:6                   ] Success client-log
15:51:35.068 I [MainView.cpp:6828               ] Load complete (0) url: sp://38c77ecc7b659570b5f3edb3f83c0cf13c8a56e8.browse/index.html
15:51:35.973 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:1002] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Snapshot-updated to revision 1837,6e2a70db85fcead0f9ee01e4414a913667b980c0
15:51:35.993 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5yolys8XG4q7YfjYGl5Lff] Synchronization starting: GET (from revision 0,726f6f7400000000000000000000000000000000) 
15:51:37.562 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:1002] [spotify:user:z:publishedrootlist] Snapshot-updated to revision 132,431ef37f4820b65b00cbb78588c7f131fde7b620
15:51:37.582 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:1GQLlzxBxKTb6tJsD4RxHI] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 1603,a9abddb926692f87959ae2310873e27f4e464a17) 
content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.
15:51:37.929 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:3wmadCOASzVtYyFNM48mYk] Delta-updated to revision 157,865c3d172d544a96188776ffbc1bc3c914d8fe06 (no new changes)
15:51:37.951 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:0lbtgFu3JNKX77J5YOpW7n] Synchronization starting: GET (from revision 0,726f6f7400000000000000000000000000000000) 
15:51:39.629 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:0G4dLya8wKCG4P6e4p2m6c] Delta-updated to revision 25,10178c3886bdb8e2d6e52cbaced5b9f8c94869e6 (no new changes)
15:51:39.630 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:7g6K4NOFD2eLb3i7KbmMdK] Delta-updated to revision 52,c7a9f51eee232f398a4c6951a2439342b00d69a5 (no new changes)
15:51:39.650 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:445ES7sgFV8zJHebmbUW0L] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 225,7b4860ee4ca36a5e2994ad151c56ba8c5a480b9c) 
15:51:39.651 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:06CemleTteSalaVGVMbgFy] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 423,7e9384dc6a1b63263cfd1f67077d2b75a3401ff4) 
15:51:40.119 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:1002] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5yolys8XG4q7YfjYGl5Lff] Snapshot-updated to revision 1760,9704f692cb81266b1d08c9fdb7b92bfe064663ff
15:51:40.138 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:1GQLlzxBxKTb6tJsD4RxHI] Delta-updated to revision 1606,37db3502f1702b329eedd0659039d475a7a65cc0
15:51:40.141 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5bMgwxIN2fNPSn3jjvRfE8] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 46,2b0e5478b9d36d1ca380458cb15520d5b571f335) 
15:51:40.159 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:2qlMTcW6AnnaGl7eXWAZP5] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 215,fee091e389c2a94bdc05ad236cf835fbfa30a811) 
15:51:42.149 E [facebook_scrobbler.cpp:386      ] permission denied in batch (code 403), will retry post after reauth
15:51:42.150 E [facebook_scrobbler.cpp:386      ] permission denied in batch (code 403), will retry post after reauth
15:51:42.150 E [facebook_scrobbler.cpp:386      ] permission denied in batch (code 403), will retry post after reauth
15:51:42.150 E [facebook_scrobbler.cpp:386      ] permission denied in batch (code 403), will retry post after reauth
15:51:42.150 E [facebook_scrobbler.cpp:386      ] permission denied in batch (code 403), will retry post after reauth
15:51:42.150 E [facebook_scrobbler.cpp:386      ] permission denied in batch (code 403), will retry post after reauth
15:51:42.358 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:445ES7sgFV8zJHebmbUW0L] Delta-updated to revision 225,7b4860ee4ca36a5e2994ad151c56ba8c5a480b9c (no new changes)
15:51:42.375 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:1002] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:0lbtgFu3JNKX77J5YOpW7n] Snapshot-updated to revision 921,e9475325821099bde7981ead9601b171b7f91df2
15:51:42.380 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:0Vib1QAMtMaiywa3QSEq40] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 32,c13b49a3cc8e33ebede0c33dde7f7dfbe6a92497) 
15:51:42.396 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:4Jt88XxhP2Jldzh1t3QbyF] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 310,86c5246b6ae9e4a7bc3f912e6983bc42041cba27) 
15:51:42.421 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:06CemleTteSalaVGVMbgFy] Delta-updated to revision 426,2f043d529839260b92cd4f125d5eaea6bc4bb84b
15:51:42.448 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5FJXhjdILmRA2z5bvz4nzf] Synchronization starting: GET (from revision 0,726f6f7400000000000000000000000000000000) 
15:51:44.906 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:2qlMTcW6AnnaGl7eXWAZP5] Delta-updated to revision 215,fee091e389c2a94bdc05ad236cf835fbfa30a811 (no new changes)
15:51:44.907 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5bMgwxIN2fNPSn3jjvRfE8] Delta-updated to revision 46,2b0e5478b9d36d1ca380458cb15520d5b571f335 (no new changes)
15:51:44.908 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:4Jt88XxhP2Jldzh1t3QbyF] Delta-updated to revision 310,86c5246b6ae9e4a7bc3f912e6983bc42041cba27 (no new changes)
15:51:44.927 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:4ecQaDJHF55Ls9m2lKIXbI] Synchronization starting: GET (from revision 0,726f6f7400000000000000000000000000000000) 
15:51:44.928 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:71oHxgERzA8JV1bHBJW0z1] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 81,900909781aa0ace5ba8e61f94969793c3f12e1f9) 
15:51:44.930 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:7HWcvpBmlN43XI8dAzyzeI] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 58,c75e124d30639d363171854a507aa32e3c15474e) 
15:51:45.615 I [MainView.cpp:6828               ] Load complete (0) url: sp://38c77ecc7b659570b5f3edb3f83c0cf13c8a56e8.browse/index.html
15:51:47.575 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:0Vib1QAMtMaiywa3QSEq40] Delta-updated to revision 32,c13b49a3cc8e33ebede0c33dde7f7dfbe6a92497 (no new changes)
15:51:47.596 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:collectiontracklist:6BCIP784sXOTIrOmOdvZtu] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 2452,218aa240c85d2d0fb07772afbc2aa93b74116220) 
15:51:47.643 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:1002] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:5FJXhjdILmRA2z5bvz4nzf] Snapshot-updated to revision 1807,72ed753d20a218ab1793ca59801bc584d82261ba
15:51:47.665 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:3B4R7Y9QmFXG2rPFfHfxqL] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 576,ebefddbd4c9cc6c0b586598ee2cec7d27b56ed1f) 

...


15:52:07.344 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:spotify:playlist:2JkjXscXs35c5wKE5ZeaYK] Delta-updated to revision 182,86466b30c9064a71cff18e80fbb69a58229911e5 (no new changes)
15:52:33.327 I [ApplicationPage.cpp:185         ] Keeping application browse alive for 60000 ms.
15:53:06.288 I [audio_driver_linux.cpp:19       ] Using PulseAudio
15:53:06.289 D [spirc_manager.cpp:710           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stpLoad, track=spotify:track:6eiqvJbSVJnrlhM5LrCkIX, index=5, position=0, paused=0
15:53:06.289 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1883          ] GAIA: SpircManager::becomeActiveDevice
15:53:06.289 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999491657
15:53:15.246 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999482700
15:53:15.252 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999482695
15:53:15.272 I [AppManager.cpp:258              ] Creating instance of the application playlist-header.
15:53:15.273 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:405 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:7cjxPoE4LPJnBV6ZtwoWlI] Synchronization starting: DIFF (from revision 1,cb50b271f1e90bf237abfcff0d1f91de36360da0) 
15:53:17.685 I [raven.min.js:2                  ] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_waiting' of undefined
15:53:23.392 E [ap_handler_impl.cpp:872         ] Connection error:  ap_ping_timeout
15:53:23.392 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:901      ] Connecting to AP sjc1-accesspoint-a32.ap.spotify.com:80
15:53:26.977 I [head_file_streamer.cpp:106      ] Requesting head file from CDN url: http://heads-ec.spotify.com/head/cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b 
15:53:26.977 D [spirc_manager.cpp:710           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stpLoad, track=spotify:track:1qyLekF8FRyfcdrURtx2sT, index=8, position=0, paused=0
15:53:26.977 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1883          ] GAIA: SpircManager::becomeActiveDevice
15:53:26.977 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999470970
15:53:26.977 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:53:26.982 I [sliding_window_prefetch_strategy.cpp:329] Prefetch: looks like new context - resetting window size to 1
15:53:26.987 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999470960
15:53:28.442 E [ap_connection_impl.cpp:837      ] AP Socket Error: Timeout reached (20000)
15:53:28.443 E [ap_handler_impl.cpp:872         ] Connection error:  ap_tcp_socket_timeout
15:53:28.444 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:901      ] Connecting to AP sjc1-accesspoint-a73.ap.spotify.com:4070
15:53:31.645 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:530      ] Connected to AP: 194.68.28.216:4070
15:53:33.327 I [ApplicationPage.cpp:66          ] Unloading application browse.
15:53:33.327 I [AppManager.cpp:541              ] Removing instance of application browse.

15:53:35.415 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3592076) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusRunning
15:53:35.415 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1249          ] GAIA: TIMING(3592076) SpircManager::sendSubscribe
15:53:35.415 D [spirc_manager.cpp:267           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stateTransition, kServiceStatusRunning->kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:53:35.416 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3592077) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:53:35.416 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3592077) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:53:42.538 I [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:72     ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from CDN url: http://audio-ak.spotify.com.edgesuite.net/audio/cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b?__token__=exp=1433519917~hmac=13f7eb3d46a4a0398f33326b6ec9aa9a89eaa334ac82f6bfcc999a15f43f90d9 
15:53:42.542 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999454564
15:53:42.544 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999454562
15:53:42.544 3 [playlist_be_pl4_context.cpp:904 ] [spotify:user:z:playlist:7cjxPoE4LPJnBV6ZtwoWlI] Delta-updated to revision 1,cb50b271f1e90bf237abfcff0d1f91de36360da0 (no new changes)
15:53:44.054 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1312          ] GAIA: TIMING(3600714) SpircManager::onSubscriptionSuccess
15:53:44.055 D [spirc_manager.cpp:267           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stateTransition, kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx->kServiceStatusRunning
15:53:44.055 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1378          ] GAIA: TIMING(3600715) SpircManager::sendHelloHelper
15:53:45.544 E [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:192    ] CDN failure 0->524288. Error: 301. Http: 0.
15:53:45.544 I [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:72     ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from CDN url: http://audio-fa.spotify.com/audio/cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b?96jbLUQNZqLexEZa3vtl/Dw7Hjpxcw8dqfGXkJHCuGg= 
15:53:47.056 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1407          ] GAIA: SpircManager::hermesDeviceCheck
15:53:48.547 E [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:192    ] CDN failure 0->524288. Error: 301. Http: 0.
15:53:48.547 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:54:40.438 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:54:40.489 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (524288 -> 1048576) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:55:22.335 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:55:22.440 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (1048576 -> 1572864) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:56:02.599 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999324872
15:56:04.620 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:56:04.670 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (1572864 -> 2097152) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:56:30.092 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:56:30.240 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (2097152 -> 2621440) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:56:52.336 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999275136
15:56:53.498 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:56:53.640 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (2621440 -> 3145728) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:57:26.841 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:57:26.842 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (3145728 -> 3670016) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:57:44.692 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:57:44.840 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (3670016 -> 4194304) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:58:21.557 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:58:21.640 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (4194304 -> 4496780) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:58:34.958 E [ap_handler_impl.cpp:872         ] Connection error:  ap_ping_timeout
15:58:34.958 E [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:262     ] handleApErrorCode. Error 101. Timeout: 500
15:58:35.491 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (4259840 -> 4496780) from AP for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b
15:58:41.582 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:901      ] Connecting to AP sjc1-accesspoint-a75.ap.spotify.com:4070
15:58:46.584 E [ap_connection_impl.cpp:837      ] AP Socket Error: Timeout reached (20000)
15:58:46.584 E [ap_handler_impl.cpp:872         ] Connection error:  ap_tcp_socket_timeout
15:58:46.584 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:901      ] Connecting to AP sjc1-accesspoint-a43.ap.spotify.com:4070
15:58:51.367 I [ap_connection_impl.cpp:530      ] Connected to AP: 194.68.28.244:4070
15:58:55.106 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3911766) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusRunning
15:58:55.106 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1249          ] GAIA: TIMING(3911766) SpircManager::sendSubscribe
15:58:55.106 D [spirc_manager.cpp:267           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stateTransition, kServiceStatusRunning->kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:58:55.107 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3911767) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:58:55.107 D [spirc_manager.cpp:469           ] GAIA: TIMING(3911767) SpircManager::start, _service_status=kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx
15:59:05.450 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1312          ] GAIA: TIMING(3922110) SpircManager::onSubscriptionSuccess
15:59:05.450 D [spirc_manager.cpp:267           ] GAIA: SpircManager::stateTransition, kServiceStatusInSubscribeTx->kServiceStatusRunning
15:59:05.450 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1378          ] GAIA: TIMING(3922110) SpircManager::sendHelloHelper
15:59:08.452 D [spirc_manager.cpp:1407          ] GAIA: SpircManager::hermesDeviceCheck
15:59:10.067 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:185     ] Request for file cd8b8170a2a9d55df0c3e3383feb7f5ffa050b4b complete (code: 0)
15:59:17.183 I [sliding_window_prefetch_strategy.cpp:285] Prefetch: start prefetching track  ??? : 7810c7c6b65bb19c2750f5a43c3695d764d50a16
15:59:17.183 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from AP for file 7810c7c6b65bb19c2750f5a43c3695d764d50a16
15:59:18.733 I [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:72     ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from CDN url: http://audio-ak.spotify.com.edgesuite.net/audio/7810c7c6b65bb19c2750f5a43c3695d764d50a16?__token__=exp=1433520258~hmac=420f821c2c16e61a5eb1ef427df96872dba84a222d264a0b7bceea91e900d8b5 
15:59:21.745 E [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:192    ] CDN failure 0->524288. Error: 301. Http: 0.
15:59:21.745 I [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:72     ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from CDN url: http://audio-fa.spotify.com/audio/7810c7c6b65bb19c2750f5a43c3695d764d50a16?WREgZ7qO3elmzfd9o9hSBQ7zgnRpzsrnCtbd5u4x8yk= 
15:59:24.791 E [cdn_chunk_downloader.cpp:192    ] CDN failure 0->524288. Error: 301. Http: 0.
15:59:24.791 I [ap_chunk_downloader.cpp:75      ] Requesting data (0 -> 524288) from AP for file 7810c7c6b65bb19c2750f5a43c3695d764d50a16
15:59:28.073 D [spirc_manager.cpp:668           ] GAIA:   current state ID updated to -999109691
```

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask  Honestly "a lot of lines appearing on the terminal" doesn't tell me anything. Providing the output in your question would be much more likely to obtain results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify is very slow to load for me too. I have 8 playlists, with a total of 10,000+ songs.

It takes 1-2 minutes to load - and I doubt this can be changed - remember that the Spotify for Linux preview is just that - a preview. It's unsupported.

---

I just ran in the terminal - and there was a **lot** of synchronisation. Evidently spotify stores very little between sessions on the computer. For me it was syncing all the playlists of the people I follow (so try removing them) and also syncing some public playlists I listen to.

That suggests you could try to only have 1 playlist and it might speed up (but I wouldn't be too sure).

I think another reason it's slow loading is to give you a nice user experience when it's running - better to load slow and run fast than load fast and run slow (something I think Windows 7 and 8 do).

---

Looking at your output, do you follow a lot of people, or have lots of playlists? Is your internet slow? I find that running spotify once and then quitting it means it open much, much, much quicker next time. Let me investigate running spotify with no GUI.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim noted on his answer, having lots of playlists our lots of large playlists can slow down client loading performance. This is true on all platforms, not just Linux.

It's worth noting though that there are special problems with the starred playlist, since it is a bit special. Having a huge starred playlist, or notably, subscribing to another user's starred playlist, can cause adverse performance issues when the client starts up.